# Trigger HTML5 Download Button Click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a custom download button for audio player, but don't seem to have a solution, I've tried using `a` elements but does not work. So I was wondering if it is possible to trigger HTML 5 Audio download button with JS?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
<audio id="range" src="audio/1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>

<a href="audio/1.mp3" download="filename.mp3">DownloadButton</a>
```

Refer to @adeneo's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28759734/2566313)

Comment: This codepen might help you 
https://codepen.io/pen/?template=KKmexWj

Comment: This does not work because my mp3 file is in format like this: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/soundcloud-9491a.appspot.com/o/{somemp3file}?alt=media&token=904e50be-4c38-4706-ba7f-574f37551bb7